# Is Dormammu the "satan" of the Marvel Universe?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, doctor-strange

I was watching Doctor Strange the other day and I came up with this hypothesis afterwards. I mean he does appear demonic as he is always covered up in flames and his world pretty much resembles hell according to how the bible and modern culture depicts hell to be.

I'm guessing that if this is the case then Sentry must be the God of the Marvel universe. even thought he doesn't appear so holy but he is pretty much the most powerful character in the Marvel universe as he can destroy planets, galaxies and even universes within seconds without him even noticing it. in another source I also heard that he has the strength of a million exploding suns. its also save to say that by now he is the only character to ever fight Hulk in his most powerful form ever yet still dominate him.

Comment: Are you asking about Dormammu or about Sentry?

Comment: Also, tread carefully as you seem to be wondering into the depths of 'religious texts' which is not on-topic here.

Comment: Dormammu, hey but this isnt so much about religion I mean obviously every thing has a good and evil side to it. look at greek mythology for example there is Zeus (the god of the land), Poseidon (the god of the ocean) and Heidi (the god of the underworld)

Comment: I think Mephisto is more like the 'Satan' of the Marvel universe. He looks like our universal image of the devil and he rules Hell, right?

Comment: I am perplexed as to why you would think that Sentry is the god of the Marvel Universe. As for the god of the Marvel universe, that would be the One Above All.

Comment: @Adamant I think I've explained it very well in my OP already

Comment: @Möoz To  classify what kind of supernatural beings those are (dualistic deities,  omnipotent/omnipresent (mono) theist or not) simply answer w/o reasoning by analogy to avoid censure.

Comment: @Möoz there actually are versions of the demons and angels in the Christian mythos in the Marvel Universe, so it's not really off topic as long as it is concering in-universe characters.

Comment: Pretty sure the MCU doesn't have a "God" or a "Satan", and Dormammu is just a powerful extradimensional being.

Comment: @ExplorerOfMyst - I had no idea the Greco-Roman underworld resembled the Swiss alps. :-)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gISEekxuEgk

Comment: Watch the movie again.. Dormammu was definitely not covered in flames. Surtur (Thor: Ragnarok) can fit this description.

Comment: Even then, Sutr, like most Thor material, is from Norse Paganism, not Christianity.

Answer (score 7):

Short answer: No.

Dormammu has nothing to do with Satan, though he is a [Hell-lord](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Hell_Lords_(Earth-616)).

Sentry has nothing to do with God, angels, or anything even remotely similar. He is also very clearly created on Earth by humans, so cannot in any way be "God, Creator of the Universe".

In fact, the Marvel Multiverse does have versions of the demons and angels in the Christian mythos- [Yahweh](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Yahweh_(Earth-616)), [Archangels](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Archangels_members), [Hell-lords](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Hell_Lords_members).
As to the Creator of the Multiverse, that is the [One-Above-All](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/One-Above-All_(Multiverse)).
There are multiple [hells](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Hell), each ruled by a Hell-lord, including [Lucifer](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Lucifer_(Earth-616)), [Mephisto](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Mephisto_(Earth-616)), and [Marduk Kurios](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Marduk_Kurios_(Earth-616)), who "more than many other demons claims to be the true 'Satan' or 'Devil,'" though there are [multiple demons](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Satan) who go by those names.

Comment: Perhaps worth noting Kurios is the Hell-Lord who's apparently the father to Daimon Hellstrom (AKA Son of Satan, Hellstorm) and Satana.